# Mocking custom modules in VueJS components using Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I'm trying to write a simple Jest unit test on one of my Vue components.

Tech stack: TypeScript, VueJS, Jest, Webpack,

**Structure**:

```
 root
   - src
     - invite
      - accept.ts
      - accept.vue
   - test
     - invite
       - accept.ts
   - app.ts
   - jest.config.json
   - package.json
```

I've been observing some strange behaviour when attempting to mock out a dependency module using Jest.

**src/invite/accept.ts**:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { eventBus } from './../app';

@Component
export default class InviteAccept extends Vue {

    created() {
        console.log(eventBus);
        eventBus.$emit('hideNavigation');
    };
}
```

**src/invite/accept.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Blah</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./accept.ts" lang="ts"></script>
```

**src/app.ts**

```
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise'
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Invite from './invite/accept.vue';

polyfill();

export const eventBus = new Vue();

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/invite/accept/:token', component: Invite, name: 'inviteAccept' },
        { path: '/', component: undefined, name: 'index' },
    ]
});

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

**/jest.config.json**

```
{
  "transform": {
    "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
    "\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "/test/.*\\.(ts|tsx)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "vue",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!lodash-es/.*)"
  ]
}
```

**/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest -c jest.config.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.15",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.9",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-teamcity-reporter": "^0.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.6",
    "ts-loader": "3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.2.0",
    "vue-jest": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-types": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

And finally, the test class

**/test/invite/accept.ts**

```
import InviteAccept from './../../src/invite/accept';
import { eventBus } from './../../src/app';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueRouter = require('vue-router'); // This needs to be 'require', rather than 'from'. Some weird thing or something.
import 'jest';

describe('invites', () => {
    jest.mock('./../../src/app', () => 'anything');

    function createWrapper() {
        const localVue = createLocalVue();
        localVue.use(VueRouter);
        const router = new VueRouter();

        return shallowMount(InviteAccept, {
            localVue,
            router
        });
    };

    test('should mock in test', () => {
        // this works:
        const test = require('./../../src/app');
        expect(test).toEqual('anything');
    });

    test('should mock in component', () => {
        const wrapper = createWrapper();
    });

});
```

The test called `should mock in test` gets the mocked value for `eventBus` and passes.

The test called `should mock in component` does not get the mocked value for `eventBus` and it is `undefined`. The exact error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined

      at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.InviteAccept.created (src/invite/accept.vue:49:23)
      at callHook (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:2919:21)
      at VueComponent.Vue._init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4628:5)
      at new VueComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4796:12)
      at createInstance (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:4230:12)
      at mount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5376:12)
      at Object.shallowMount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5414:10)
      at createWrapper (test/invite/accept.ts:13:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/invite/accept.ts:25:23)
```

The `console.log(eventBus);` inside the component's `created()` function also yields `undefined`.

If I try and `console.log(eventBus);` inside the test, it is `undefined` too, which i just don't understand either.

What I expect to happen is that the `eventBus` instance inside the component is replaced. I realise that the mock will never work whilst set to 'Anything' but I expect to see it set to the mocked value at least.

According to the Jest documentation (https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html) on Automatic Mocking I think the above is correct.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I have no idea what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jest.mock('./../../src/app', () => 'anything')` mocks module export with a value that factory function returns:

```
    const test = require('./../../src/app');
    expect(test).toEqual('anything');
```

Although this will work for ES module imports because they use CommonJS modules internally, this is against specs, because `*` import should be an object.

> The test called should mock in test gets the mocked value for eventBus and passes.

It doesn't get mocked `eventBus`. It gets `*` export.

> The test called should mock in component does not get the mocked value for eventBus

There is no `eventBus` property on 'anything' string, that's why the test fails.

Named export should be mocked with:

```
jest.mock('./../../src/app', () => ({
  eventBus: { $emit: jest.fn() }
}));
```

Comment: Awesome - that worked! It just went a little against my own intuition about how the mocking framework should behave. Great explanation!